# Find the longest matching string in an array

Tags: php, arrays, snmp, string-matching

I have an array of hierarchically arranged identifiers (SNMP sysObjectIDs), that I'd like to match against in order to find the closest match.

For example, if my array contains :

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.207         = alliedware
.1.3.6.1.4.1.207.1.14    = alliedwareplus
.1.3.6.1.4.1.207.1.4.126 = allied-radlan
.1.3.6.1.4.1.207.1.4.125 = allied-radlan
```

And I search for

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.207.1.14.69
```

I would like it to return the alliedwareplus entry.

If I search for

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.207.1.4
```

It should return the alliedware entry.

Basically I just want to return the longest match starting from the beginning of the string.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reminds me of a binary tree. :)

Comment: The solutions I came up with off the top of my mind would be really slow and would only mess with performance. I'll pay close attention to the answers you receive.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me and returns the correct test results based on your description.

```
function find_match($data,$search) {
  $keys = array_keys($data);

  usort($keys,function($a,$b){
    return strlen($b)-strlen($a);
  });

  foreach($keys as $key){
    if (substr($search,0,strlen($key)) == $key)
      return $data[$key];
  }
}

$data = array(
  '.1.3.6.1.4.1.207'         => 'alliedware',
  '.1.3.6.1.4.1.207.1.14'    => 'alliedwareplus',
  '.1.3.6.1.4.1.207.1.4.126' => 'allied-radlan',
  '.1.3.6.1.4.1.207.1.4.125' => 'allied-radlan',
);

find_match($data,'.1.3.6.1.4.1.207.1.14.69'); // => 'alliedwareplus'
find_match($data,'.1.3.6.1.4.1.207.1.4');     // => 'alliedware'
```

Comment: What would this make when prefix matching ".1.3.6.1.4.1.207" vs ".1.3.6.1.4.1.20"? It's a very important distinction in SNMP, to make sure you compare the numbers, rather than prefix matching the string representations. My Php is not good enough to determine if that's what you did here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the array by the number of components in the object ID, from high to low.
2. Loop through the array, testing whether the object ID in the array is a prefix of the input object ID.
3. When you find a match like this, break out of the loop.

All these steps will probably be easiest if you first convert all the object IDs to an array:

```
$objid_arr = explode('.', $objid);
```